# integrate redmine_helpdesk in Redmine

Tags: debian, migration, redmine

I installed a Redmine 3.3 from the current git repository I want to use Redmine as a simply helpdesk for clients. I made a choice to redmine_helpdesk and checked it out from Github. I can see the plugin in Redmine under installed plugins and configured a cronjob for fetching the e-mails from my IMAP account. If I run it manually I get this output:

```
app@redmine:~/redmine$ rake -f /home/app/redmine/Rakefile redmine:email:receive_imap RAILS_ENV="production" host=m
ail.host.tld port=143 username=support@domain.tld password=pass folder=INBOX move_on_success=processed
move_on_failure=failed no_permission_check=1 unkown_user=accept starttls=1 --trace
** Invoke redmine:email:receive_imap (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute redmine:email:receive_imap
```

So I think there is no I can fetch the e-mails, but I don't see the e-mails as a ticket (in project support) in Redmine. 
I followed the introduction of redmine_helpdesk but I don't have a clue where I add the permission 'Treat as supportclient' to all roles which I want to be treated as supportclient (the permission is automatically added to the 'Anonymous' role) and where I can disable standard notifications for non-anonymous supportclients to prevent their spamming (optional)

What's the solution for my special problem?